# JQuery Ajax PHP validating signup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to validate my sign up form with Jquery which runs after a user submits the form.

I have following jquery function:

```
$('#signupForm').submit(function() {

    if($('#email').val() == "" || 
        $('#password').val() == "" ||
        $('#repassword').val() == "" ){
            alert('empty form');
        return false;
    }

    if($('#password').val() != $('#repassword').val()){
        alert('password does not match');
        return false;
    }

    //check if email is available
    var isemailavailable = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: "php_includes/registerlogic.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {checkemail: $('#email').val()},
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data){

            var resultObject = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
            //alert(data);
            console.log(resultObject.data);
        if(resultObject.data=='taken') {

                //return false;
                console.log('inside taken');
                isemailavailable = false;
                console.log(isemailavailable);
            }else{
                alert($.trim(data));
                isemailavailable = true;
            }
    });

    if(isemailavailable == false){
        alert("email already exists!");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Ajax hits this page for email availability:

```
if(isset($_POST["checkemail"])){
$email = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['checkemail']);
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email= :email LIMIT 1', array(':email'=>$_POST['checkemail']));

$isavailable = "";
if(count($query) < 1){
    $isavailable = 'available';
}else{
    $isavailable = 'taken';
}

$respond = array("data" => $isavailable);
$out = json_encode($respond);
echo $out;
exit();
```

}

Ok so my problem here is with Jquery, everything works fine until where I have the if(isemailavailable == false) part. The code never goes inside the if even though isemailavailable is false. Hence the form will be submitted as "return false" is inside the if statement. I have also tried if(!isemailavailable) and it didnt work aswell.

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.
Thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `if` statement runs before the ajax request is completed.

You should move that code-block to inside the `.done()` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php_includes/registerlogic.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {checkemail: $('#email').val()},
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(data){

        var resultObject = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
        //alert(data);
        console.log(resultObject.data);
        if(resultObject.data=='taken') {

            //return false;
            console.log('inside taken');
            isemailavailable = false;
            console.log(isemailavailable);
        }else{
            alert($.trim(data));
            isemailavailable = true;
        }


        if(isemailavailable == false){
          alert("email already exists!");
          //return false;
        }

});
```

Although you don't need that extra `if` when you handle everything inside that function.

Returning `false` would also not do what you expect it to do there so that is not necessary either.

You probably should run the validation on the e-mail field as soon as it loses focus and disable your submit button while it is not valid.

**An alternative** would be to set `async` to false to get a synchronous ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php_includes/registerlogic.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {checkemail: $('#email').val()},
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
}).done(function(data){
```

but personally I would do the e-mail validation right after the field loses focus / as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. Yes that did gave me the alert("email already exists") which means its now working but the return false is not stoping the form from submiting. Any idea why this is hapening? Seems like return false wont work inside ajax done()

Comment: @user3170763 I just added something about that at the end of my answer.

Comment: Oh yes sorry just saw that. Ok I will try to validate after it looses focus on a separate function. Thank you so much for the help. :)